# c# multiple SetCursorPosition but first one gets skipped

Tags: c#

Hi in my c# console app I have a method which calls `Console.SetCursorPosition` multiple times for several user inputs however the first one gets skipped when I run the program. I would like my output to look like:

First name: (cursor here)

Last name:

address:

Phone:

email:

Currently the cursor appears next to last name.
Any ideas to why this might happen would be much appreciated.

```
String firstNameLbl = "First Name:";
String lastNameLbl = "Last Name:";
String addressLbl = "Address:";
String phoneLbl = "Phone Number:";
String emailLbl = "Email Address:";

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + heading1.Length / 2) + "}", heading1));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + heading2.Length / 2) + "}", heading2));

Console.Write("\n" + String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + firstNameLbl.Length - 3) + "}", firstNameLbl));
Console.Write("\n" + String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + lastNameLbl.Length - 3) + "}", lastNameLbl));
Console.Write("\n" + String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + addressLbl.Length - 3) + "}", addressLbl));
Console.Write("\n" + String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + phoneLbl.Length - 3) + "}", phoneLbl));
Console.Write("\n" + String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + emailLbl.Length - 3) + "}", emailLbl));

Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + firstNameLbl.Length - 3, 3);
firstName = Console.ReadLine();


Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + lastNameLbl.Length - 3, 4);
lastName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + addressLbl.Length - 3, 5);
address = Console.ReadLine();

Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + phoneLbl.Length - 3, 6);
phoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + emailLbl.Length - 3, 7);
email = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: just tested and it works without a problem... maybe you got some other funky console settings?

Comment: How do you know the last name is going to be output on row 4? You don't set the cursor position before writing the label, so it's going to be output on whatever row the cursor was at before you started the program.

Comment: hmmm okay maybe one of my other methods is somehow messing with it

Comment: Don't confuse the mouse cursor with the console cursor.  Moving the mouse is not useful.   If you display the text first, then want to guide the user to answer the questions one by one then use the Console.CursorTop/Left properties.